# Can Aleph Numbers be multiplied?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, infinity

i.e., does it make sense to say something like $(2 * \aleph_0) > \aleph_0$ ?

The original question I was thinking about is:

if A = $\mathbb{Z}$ and B = {the set of even integers} is it correct to say that |A| = 0.5|A| + 0.5|B| ?

Comment: The set of even integers has the same cardinality as the set of all integers.

Comment: Though this won't help you with integers vs. even integers, just as a point of curiosity, you might be interested in [ordinal arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic) where we have infinite elements like $\omega$ such that $2\omega > \omega$.

Comment: @Meelo According to the traditional notation for ordinal multiplication (maybe it changed recently?), $2\omega=\omega$ and $\omega2=\omega+\omega\gt\omega$.

Comment: @bof Whoops - you're right. (Too bad that that's the standard order for the notation, though. It looks so silly)

Comment: @Meelo I suppose so, but wouldn't it look sillier to have to write $\alpha^{\beta+\gamma}=\alpha^\gamma\alpha^\beta$ instead of $\alpha^{\beta+\gamma}=\alpha^\beta\alpha^\gamma$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aleph numbers can certainly be multiplies, but not to give the results you mention. In fact, $2\aleph_0=\aleph_0$ and there is no such thing as fractional alephs so $0.5|A|$ is meaningless.

For the sets $A$ and $B$ you mention it is very easy to establish a bijection and thus $|A|=|B|$.

Comment: The bijection is $f : A \to B$, $f(a) = 2a$, $f^{-1} : B \to A$, $f^{-1}(b) = b/2$.

Comment: @Axoren I appreciate your comment here however please note that it's not a very constructive one. I deliberately left an explicit bijection from the answer in order to give the reader something to figure out (and it is a very simple detail). The comments to answers are intended to improve the answer, or to address previous comments. I find that your comment is actually not helpful. One should not be spoon-fed.

Comment: Hmm. Could you explain why $2*\aleph_0 = \aleph_0$, and why there are no such things as fractional alephs? I already knew about the bijection, by the way; it's trivial and probably the first bijection anyone learns.

Comment: @mchenja this isn't the place to teach you the very basic facts of the theory of cardinals. You can find plenty of introductory material online or in books that will teach you these things.